# Was ist eine "Lätsch" auf Hochdeutsch?

Tags: single-word-request, dialect, swabian

Im schwäbischen Dialekt gibt es für den im folgenden Bild gezeigten Gesichtsausdruck

[image: Eine Lätsch]

den Ausdruck **"Lätsch"** ([hergeleitet von](http://books.google.de/books?id=8IPVZwinb9oC&lpg=PA297&ots=w7yBOuNIqh&dq=%22L%C3%A4tsch%22%20schw%C3%A4bisch&hl=de&pg=PA297#v=onepage&q&f=false) italienisch *laccio*, Schlinge). Typischerweise werden die Mundwinkel herabgezogen und die Unterlippe  nach vorne gestülpt.

> "Zieh doch koi so e Lätsch!" – *Ziehe doch keine solche "Lätsch"!*
>   "Er macht etz wieder sei Lätsch na." – *Er macht jetzt wieder seine "Lätsch".*
>   "Dem hängt sei Lätsch bis uff de Bode 'ra" – hängt seine "Lätsch" bis auf den Boden herab.*

Was wäre die passende hochdeutsche Bezeichnung für diesen Gesichtsaudruck?

Comment: Das Vorstülpen der Unterlippe und Herabziehen der Mundwinkel bei (insbesondere) kleinen Kindern heißt (zumindest regional) auch "eine Schippe machen". Eine Dreijährige, die keinen zweiten Nachtisch bekommt und ein Gesicht kurz vorm Losweinen zieht, macht eine Schippe.

Comment: Ich kenne es nur für Kinder und habe es deshalb lieber mal als Kommentar in den Ring geworfen. Aber auch den kannst Du ja gern upvoten. `:)`

Comment: Ein wirklich schöner Fund! Mach doch eine Antwort draus. Meine Stimme haste. `:)`

Comment: Oooch, ich habe sogar auf SO lange schon aufgehört, rep zu sammeln. Nun ist es ja bekannt, das reicht mir. `:)`

Comment: In Österreich heißt diese Mund-Haltung nicht "Lätsch" sondern "Fotz" oder "Fotze". Die Tätigkeit dazu heißt "einen Fotz ziehen" oder "eine Fotze ziehen". Da man beim Mundharmonikaspielen die Lippen recht ähnlich hält, und dabei mit dem Instrument über den Mund hobelt, wird die Mundharmonika in ländlichen Gebieten Österreichs und Südbayerns auch "Fotzhobel" oder "Fotzenhobel" genannt. Siehe auch: http://wissen.schoelnast.at/beitraege/beitrag_2012-09-11.html

Comment: Du weißt hoffentlich, dass dieser Ausdruck im Hochdeutschen **ausschließlich** ein wenig schöner Vulgärausdruck ist ([Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Fotze)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Aus Kommentaren:*

Das Vorstülpen der Unterlippe und Herabziehen der Mundwinkel bei (insbesondere) kleinen Kindern heißt (zumindest regional) auch **"eine Schippe machen"**. Eine Dreijährige, die keinen zweiten Nachtisch bekommt und ein Gesicht kurz vorm Losweinen zieht, macht eine Schippe.

Dies belegen auch folgende Zitate:

> - »Och!« sagt Weio wegwerfend und macht wieder eine Schippe <sup>Fallada Wolf 1,267</sup>
> - *"schippe verzogenes maul (nach der gestalt der vorgeschobenen unterlippe)"* Liesenberg 194. Albrecht 200b <sup>[Grimm](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GS09138)</sup>

Comment: "Schippe" kenne ich nur als Teutonismus für das Wort "Schaufel". Kann sein, dass das in einigen Gegenden Deutschlands verwendung findet, aber Hochdeutsch ist "Schippe" auf keinen Fall.

Answer (score 7):

Das Wort **"[Schnute](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Schnute)"** ist hierfür im Norden recht gebräuchlich, ebenfalls mit "ziehen".

Wiktionary (Link s.o.) definiert es u.a. als einen "verdrossen oder ablehnend verzogener Mund" und bringt für diese Bedeutung folgende Beispiele:

> Zieh doch nicht so eine Schnute.
>
> Die Zuhörer zogen solche Schnuten, dass ich mich immer wieder während meines Vortrags verhaspelte.
>
> „Und ihre Tochter zog eine mißmutige Schnute und stampfte hörbar ungehalten.“

Comment: Für mich (Schwabe!) wäre dies eine Schnute: http://h12.abload.de/img/schnute1474c.jpg

Comment: @Takkat Schnute gilt für beides, Daum und den Wanna-Be-Popstar. Allgemein das Verziehen des Mundes oder gar ganzen Gesichts, nur um Ablehnung, Missfallen, Unzufriedenheit, etc. auszudrücken.

Comment: "Schnute" ist meiner Wahrnehmung nach ein typisches Berlinerisches Dialektwort. Ich halte es für undenkbar, dass ein Nachrichtensprecher im Fernsehen das Wort "Schnute" verwenden würde, wenn er das Beispielfoto beschreiben müsste. Zumindest im Österreichischen Fernsehen ist das undenkbar.

Answer (score 7):

Es gibt auch noch das Wort *der Flunsch*. Eine Google-Bildsuche bringt viele [Treffer](http://www.google.de/search?q=flunsch&hl=de&client=opera&hs=825&rls=de&channel=suggest&prmd=imvns&source=lnms&tbm=isch&ei=oWhPT-XHDsOcOqjQjJAK&sa=X&oi=mode_link&ct=mode&cd=2&ved=0CBkQ_AUoAQ&biw=1333&bih=656), die Daum sehr ähnlich sehen.
Man bildet es auch mit ziehen.

> Ich ziehe einen Flunsch.

Laut [Wiktionary](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Flunsch) ist es mit flennen verwandt.

Comment: Flunsch ist nicht Hochdeutsch. Stell dir einen Nachrichtensprecher vor, der (aus welchem Grund auch immer) dieses Foto beschreiben würde. Das Wort "Flunsch" würde man dabei sicherlich nicht hören.

Comment: Ich kann mir auch keinen Nachrichtensprecher vorstellen, der "pupst" sagt und doch denke ich, dass das Hochdeutsch ist.

Answer (score 3):

Ich denke, die beste Antwort ist wohl

> Schmollmund