# Was genau ist ein "Teutonismus"?

Tags: single-word-request, meaning-in-context, meaning

Erst durch Kommentare wie diesen

> "Schippe" kenne ich nur als **Teutonismus** für das Wort "Schaufel". Kann sein, dass das in einigen Gegenden Deutschlands verwendung findet, aber Hochdeutsch ist "Schippe" auf keinen Fall. <sup>[Link](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/4047/was-ist-eine-latsch-auf-hochdeutsch#comment13726_5384)</sup>

bin ich auf den Begriff *"Teutonismus"* gestoßen.

Was versteht man im deutschsprachigen außerdeutschen Raum darunter?

---

<sub>*Anmerkung:* Es geht mir hier vor allem um die Bedeutung **außerhalb** der Bundesrepublik Deutschland, da naturgemäß in Deutschland (anders als in Österreich) der Begriff *Teutonismus* nicht, oder nur in einer ganz anderen, **abwertenden** Bedeutung benutzt wird. Vor allem deshalb ist selbst unter Germanisten in der Bundesrepublik Deutschland die Verwendung des Begriffs *"Teutonismus"* sehr umstritten.</sub>

Comment: Ehrlich gesagt verstehe ich (mit einer Mundart aus den südosteuropäischen deutschen Sprachinseln) darunter nicht viel.  Begriffe wie *deutschländisch*, *bundesrepublikanisch*, *preussisch*, *neudeutsch* usw sind nützlicher wenn die Basis des eigenen Dialekts sowieso aus Schwaben/Pfalz/Elsass usw ist, Wörter wie *GEZ-Gebühr* oder *Türsprechanlage* aber nicht wirklich kennt.  Allgemein halt ich es für sprachwissenschaftlich verwirrend, dass die BRD (und ihre Vorgänger) sich mit "den Deutschen" gleichsetzt, und wer *Teutonismus* verwendet, erklärt sich irgendwie damit einverstanden. ;-)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### Sprach-Varietäten

Ebenso wenig wie es nicht eine einzige englische Sprache gibt, gibt es auch nicht eine einzige deutsche Sprache. Bei der englischen Sprache unterscheidet man zwei große Standardvarietäten, nämlich "British English" und "American English".

Die deutsche Sprache kennt drei Standardvarietäten:

- deutsches Deutsch
- österreichisches Deutsch
- schweizerisches Deutsch

Alle drei Varietäten sind gleichberechtigte Hochsprachen, also keine Dialekte. Insbesondere ist das schweizerische (Hoch-)Deutsch vom Schwizerdeutsch zu unterscheiden. Schwizerdeutsch ist ein Dialekt, der keine geregelte Rechtschreibung kennt, während schweizerischers Deutsch eine Hochsprache mit festen Rechtschreibregeln ist.

**Deutsches Deutsch** wird in Deutschland, Belgien und Luxemburg gesprochen und dort auch an Schulen unterrichtet. Es gibt kein amtliches Wörterbuch für diese Varietät. Der Duden hat diesen Status im Jahr 1996 verloren.

**Österreichisches Deutsch** wird in Österreich und Italien (Südtirol) gesprochen und in Schulen unterrichtet. Das amtliche Wörterbuch dieser Varietät ist das Österreichische Wörterbuch, das vom österreichischen Bundesministerium für Unterricht und Kunst herausgegeben wird und auch in Italien (Südtirol) gültig ist.

**Schweizerisches Deutsch** wird in Schulen der Schweiz unterrichtet und von Schweizern als geschriebene Sprache verwendet, während im Alltag meist Schwizerdeutsch gesprochen wird. Ob es ein amtliches Wörterbuch für diese Varietät gibt, weiß ich leider nicht.

---

### Teutonismus

Ein Teutonismus ist nun ein Begriff, der nur in der Varietät "deutsches Deutsch" Verwendung findet und in Gegenden, in denen eine andere Varietät gelehrt und verwendet wird, entweder unbekannt ist oder als fremd empfunden wird.

**Beispiele:**
Schippe (Schaufel)
Apfelsine (Orange)
pellen (schälen)
Abitur (A+CH:Matura)
Vorfahrt (A:Vorrang, CH:Vortritt)
hochgehen (hinauf gehen)

Wegen der Übermacht von Medien (TV + Zeitschriften), die in deutschem Deutsch publizieren und auch in Gebieten anderer Varietäten konsumiert werden, wird deutsches Deutsch im gesamten deutschen Sprachraum verstanden. Es wird aber in Österreich, Italien und der Schweiz nicht aktiv verwendet.

---

### Austriazismus

Ein Austriazismus ist ein Begriff, der nur in der Varietät "österreichisches Deutsch" Verwendung findet und außerhalb Österreichs entweder unbekannt ist oder als fremd empfunden wird.

**Beispiele:**
Marille (Aprikose)
Hendl (Hühnchen)
abgehen (fehlen) - Du bist mir abgegangen. = Du hast mir gefehlt.
Brösel (Krümel)
Adventkalender (Adventskalender)
Schweinsbraten (Schweinebraten)
Germ (Hefe)
Türschnalle (Türklinke)

---

### Helvetismus

Dasselbe wie oben, jedoch auf schweizerisches Deutsch bezogen.

**Beispiele:**
Baumnuss (Walnuss)
Hahnenwasser (Leitungswasser)
Poulet (Hühnchen)
Ständerlampe (Stehlampe)
Türfalle (Türklinke)
Automobilist (Autofahrer)

---

Ich möchte nochmal ausdrücklich betonen, dass die hier aufgelisteten Beispiele **KEINE** Dialektwörter sind, sondern dass es sich hier um Begriffe der jeweiligen Varietät der deutschen Hochsprache handelt.

Auch zu erwähnen ist, dass es auch Unterschiede in der Grammatik gibt.

Comment: Wobei noch zu erwähnen wäre, dass einige der erwähnten Teutonismen keineswegs überall in Deutschland üblich sind. So wird kein Bayer je eine Apfelsine pellen, sondern eine Orange schälen. Umgekehrt kann man in Bayern durchaus ein Hendl bekommen. Zu beachten ist außerdem, dass manche Wörter zwar sowohl in Deutschland als auch in Österreich verwendet werden, aber einen unterschiedlichen Bedeutungsumfang haben (Beispiel: "Mist" ist in Deutschland nur das, was vom Vieh produziert wird, während der Begriff in Österreich auch für Müll verwendet wird). Für D/CH und A/CH gilt vermutlich dasselbe.

Comment: Ehrlich? Brösel und Hahnenwasser wären mir (=Teutone ;) ) nie als fremd aufgefallen, nur als nicht-hochdeutsch...

Comment: Mir, als altem Teutonen, klingt "Teutonismus" abwertend. Verhöre ich mich da?

Comment: @userunknown: Ja, da verhörst du dich. Wenn wir zu einem Deutschen "Piefke" sagen, ist das ironisch-abwertend gemeint, aber auf "Teutonismus" trifft das nicht zu, dieser Begriff wird ganz wertfrei verwendet. Das gilt auch für die Schwester-Wörter Austriazismus und Helvetismus. Damit soll nichts auf- oder abgewertet werden.

Comment: @celtschk: Die Definition verlangt nicht, dass das Wort im gesamten Sprachgebiet üblich ist. Das Wort "Fleischhauer" ist beispielsweise nur im Osten Österreichs üblich (dort aber Teil der Hochsprache wie man sie auf Geschäftsschildern, im Branchenverzeichnis und in Tageszeitungen findet), während in Tirol und Vorarlberg stattdessen das Wort "Metzger" verwendet wird, das dafür in Ostösterreich wieder fremd klingt.

Comment: Bayern (vor allem Altbayern, nicht so sehr Franken und Schwaben) sprechen ein Deutsch, dass der österreichischen Varietät oftmals näher als der deutschen ist. Dasselbe gilt für Vorarlberger, die der schweizerischen Varietät näher stehen als der österreichischen. Hier stimmen einfach die Landesgrenzen nicht mit den Sprachgrenzen überein, wodurch es zu Überschneidungen und Mischformen kommt. Das tut den Definitionen der Begriffe jedoch keinen Abbruch.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Ich habe nirgendwo behauptet, dass die Begriffsdefinition falsch wäre. Aber ich halte es für wichtig zu erwähnen, dass nicht alle Teutonismen in ganz Deutschland üblich (oder auch nur bekannt) sind, weil eben jemand, der nur die Definitionen liest, eben fälschlicherweise diesen Eindruck bekommen könnte. Es handelt sich bei meinem Kommentar also nicht um eine Korrektur, sondern um eine Ergänzung.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Laut Linguistik ist meines Wissens nach der in Nürnberg gesprochene Dialekt nicht etwa "Mittelfränkisch", wie man vermuten würde, sondern (und das gefällt mir als gebürtigem Nürnberger gar nicht mal so sehr) "Bayerisch-Österreichisch"... Das liegt aber an früheren Einwanderungen nach (Nord)Bayern.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar: Ja, das stimmt, der Dialekt heißt "Bayerisch-Österreichisch", wobei das ja auch eher eine Gruppe von vielen Dialekten ist (Münchner reden anders als Tiroler, diese anders als Kärntner und diese wieder anders als Wiener). Aber hier ging es ja ausdrücklich *NICHT* um Dialekte, sondern um Varietäten der Hochsprache.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Ich weiß - ich wollte nur mein Leid mal klagen, dass ich als Franke "Bayerisch-Österreichisch" sprechen soll :-)

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar: Du sollst Hochdeutsch sprechen! :)

Comment: Tu ich ja :-) Hier geht's um's Prinzip :-D

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar Man muss Gott eben für alles danken ;p

Comment: Es gibt andere (zum Teil auch rechtlich anerkannte) deutschsprachige Gemeinden außerhalb der erwähnten Ländern.  In Rumänien zB.  Schriftsprache vermischt deutschländische und österreichische Elemente.

Comment: Die Antwort sollte Englisch lieber nicht erwähnen, was da oben steht ist eine extreme Vereinfachung der eigentlichen Lage.

Comment: In [de_LI](http://www.unicode.org/cldr/charts/24/summary/de_LI.html) scheint man auch noch eine vom Rest abgrenzbare deutsche Sprachvarietäten zu haben. Ist wohl nur eine Mischung aus de_DE und de_CH.

Comment: @dakab: Nein. In Liechtenstein wird in den Schulen dasselbe Deutsch wie in der Schweiz unterrichtet. Die Schweizer Varietät der deutschen Sprache ist in Liechtenstein die Amtssprache. In Liechtenstein wird daher, wie in der Schweiz, kein ß verwendet. Es gibt auch keine eigene belgische oder luxemburgische Varietät der Deutschen Sprache, obwohl es auf Computern auch die Lokale-Einstellungen de_BE und de_LU gibt. Mich wundert, dass es kein de_IT, de_US und kein de_NA gibt, denn in Italien, USA und Namibia wird auch Deutsch gesprochen.

Comment: Brösel empfinde ich trotz meiner norddeutschen sprachlichen Prägung nicht als fremd. Sicherlich ist es in Deutschland bekannt! Ich werde mich trotzdem noch umhören! Der Unterschied mag darin bestehen, dass man im Norden nicht Bröseln sagt - es sei denn als Verb!

Answer (score 3):

Da Teutonismus Wörter und Ausdrücke beschreibt, die nur in Deutschland vorkommen, versteht man überall das gleiche unter diesem Begriff. Neben dem Teutonismus gibt es auch noch den Austriazismus (Wörter und Ausdrücke die nur bei uns in Österreich gebraucht werden), sowie den Helvetismus (das gleiche für die Schweiz).

Answer (score 2):

Ein Teutonismus ist ein Begriff, der nur im deutschländischen Standarddeutsch vorkommt, also im deutschschweizerischen und im österreichischen Standarddeutsch nicht.

Ein Germanismus ist ein ursprünglich deutscher Begriff, der in andern Sprachen vorkommt.

---

Das Nomen *Schippe* ist ein Regionalismus aus Norddeutschland, also umgangssprachlich, und deshalb nicht deutschländisches Standarddeutsch. Es bedeutet gemeindeutsch (Standard in Österreich, Deutschland und der Schweiz) *Spaten.*

- Deutschschweizerisches Standarddeutsch: *Stechschaufel*
- Österreichisches Standarddeutsch: *Grabscheit*

Comment: Ich bin in Österreich geboren, lebe seit 50 Jahren in Österreich und spreche seit 50 Jahren österreichisches Deutsch. Aber das Wort »Grabscheit« habe ich noch nie gehört. Es steht auch nicht im ÖWB (Österreichisches Wörterbuch, das ist das Standard-Wörterbuch des österreichischen Deutsch). Hast du das frei erfunden?

Comment: `Grabscheit` habe ich auch noch nie gehört. Eine Quelle dafür, dass dieses Wort in Österreich verbreitet ist oder war, wäre interessant.

Comment: Duden sagt, Grabscheit ist landschaftlich: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Grabscheit und selten; Bedeutung: Spaten. Ostarrichi bescheinigt dem Wort Grabscheit, es sei historisch und veraltet: http://www.ostarrichi.org/word-18663-Spaten_Das_Umstechen_der_Erde_wird-Grabscheit.html

Comment: *Schippe* bedeutet eher allgemein *Schaufel* als speziell *Spaten*, einen Spaten würde ich nicht als *Schippe* bezeichnen (ebensowenig wie als *Schaufel*, ist einfach ein anderes Werkzeug)